# Prove that there does not exist a polynomial...

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove that there does not exist a polynomial $p(x)$ with real coefficients such that $p(n) = \log(n)$ for all positive integers $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: If such polynom exists then $p$ is not constant so :
$$\dfrac{log(n)}{p(n)} = 1 \to 1$$
But we know that :
$$\dfrac{log(n)}{p(n)} \to 0$$

Comment: Hint: what can you say about roots of $q(x)=p(x^2)-2p(x)$ ?

Answer (score 5):

Let's say $p(x)$ is of degree $m$. What do you know about
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{p(x)}{x^m}$$
and what do you know about
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log(x)}{x^m}?$$

Comment: According to [site regulations](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards), answering questions without context and where the OP does not show any effort is not advised.

Comment: @Gary It's not a full answer to the question but a hint in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you @principal-ideal-domain .